# Transfer logs from kafka to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, apache-kafka, logstash, filebeat

I am looking for the light-weight log shipper which can directly transfer my logs to elasticsearch from kafka. Out of Filebeat, Logagent, Logstash(but i need light weighted) which among them or others can suites my use-case the best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[rsyslog](https://www.rsyslog.com/) is lightweight. As from version 8.27, it supports [kafka](https://www.rsyslog.com/tag/imkafka/) as input. Elasticsearch as output is supported from even earlier.

[image]

Kafka input module configuration is described [here](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/imkafka.html)

Elasticsearch output module configuration is described [here](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/omelasticsearch.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you please share some more links to make the configuration that read from kafka to ES more clear.